Visual Studio save on hot reload
This question sounds almost like "hot reload on save" with hundreds of results, and that is making it impossible to google.
Is there a way to make Visual Studio (2022 if relevant) save the currently open file when  I click "Hot Reload"? So that the version as I see it is hot reloaded instead of whenever I last saved.
